# Viewing GCC Optimization Intermediates in GDB?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, optimization, gdb

I have a C++ program that I am trying to debug with GDB. I am building it with optimization, and I often run into the case where I want to debug something like:

```
int newVar = someArray[thing1 + thing2];
```

However, GCC is smart and optimizes code heavily. Perhaps at that point only intermediate `thing1 + thing2` is stored, with the individual `thing1` and `thing2` having been overwritten. When I ask GDB to print `thing1`, I get `<value optimized out>`. Same for `thing2`.

So I have two questions:

1. If I ask gdb to `p thing1 + thing2`, is it smart enough to realize that that intermediate is currently stored in a register? Or is it just going to try to naively evaluate the expression, realize that both the variables it uses are optimized out, and fail?
2. How can I get a listing of what expression-evaluation intermediates are actually available at any given point in an execution? If it's storing `&someArray + sizeof(int) * thing2` as the intermediate instead, I would like to know that. Does GCC not include sufficiently detailed information about its optimizations for GDB to figure out what intermediates are actually stored/how the compiler has decided to use each register? Is there some super-detailed multi-megabyte debugging info format that I could instruct GCC to produce? Is there another compiler/debugger pair that handles this better?

If I were to spend 20 minutes tracing through the assembly for the function, noting where `thing1` and `thing2` come in and when whatever is derived from them meets up with the address of `someArray`, I would be able to work this out manually. But I want the debugger to do it for me, since the compiler had to track all this stuff to do the optimization in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

> If I ask gdb to p thing1 + thing2, is it smart enough to realize that that intermediate is currently stored in a register?

No, it will try the naive thing and fail.

> How can I get a listing of what expression-evaluation intermediates are actually available at any given point in an execution?

You can't.

> But I want the debugger to do it for me, since the compiler had to track all this stuff to do the optimization in the first place.

The compiler *did* track all this stuff, but then discarded the info after it generated the assembly. Without that info, the debugger can't possibly reconstruct it. (Well, in theory it's possible to do, but in practice it's very hard for any sufficiently aggressively optimized code.)

Having the compiler not discard the info is possible in theory, but is not practical: the resulting binary would be way too big, and I don't believe that current debugging formats support "the value of this complicated expression is stored in that register" descriptions well (if at all).

Comment: GCC/GDB don't support it. Apparently MSVC++ 2014 is getting such extended debugging information, but it already had a cleaner debug format anyway (separate PDB files)

Comment: @MSalters Separate PDB files have *nothing* to do with the format being cleaner (GCC/GDB does support separating debugging info from main executable in a similar fasion). Whether the Microsoft debug format is cleaner or not we can't tell: it's not documented. My experience with it from 8 years ago tells me it's anything but.

Comment: So I guess my solution is "develop and get support merged into GDB and GCC for a super-detailed, super-large debugging info format that can do what I want". Good to know.